# How to best add assumption that many variables are positive?

Tags: assumptions

I often need to check whether integrals are solvable in closed form and use a notebook with 5–10 variables that need to be assumed positive. Is there a better way of doing this than adding the clunky line:

`$Assumptions=a>0&&b>0&&c>0&&d>0&&f>0;` ?

I tried `$Assumptions={a,b,c,d,f}>0;` but it didn't work.

Comment: `$Assumptions=Thread[{a,b,c,d,f}>0]`?

Comment: also `$Assumptions=Element[{a,b,c,d,f}, PositiveReals]`

Comment: @kglr Both worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$Assumptions = Element[{a, b, c, d, f}, PositiveReals] ;
Simplify[Sign[a + b + c]]
```

> ```
>  1
> ```

```
$Assumptions = {};
Simplify[Sign[a + b + c]]
```

> ```
>  Sign[a + b + c]
> ```

```
$Assumptions = Thread[{a, b, c, d, f} > 0] ;
Simplify[Sign[a + b + c]]
```

> ```
>  1
> ```

```
$Assumptions = AllTrue[{a,b,c,d,f}, Positive] ;
Simplify[Sign[a+b+c]]
```

> ```
>  1
> ```